# Why was GetEnumerator() stored in a separate interface from IEnumerator?

Tags: c#, iterator, ienumerable, ienumerator

I was wondering why the GetEnumerator() method was factored out of IEnumerator and placed in IEnumerable.  It seems to me that it would make more sense to keep all of the enumerator methods in IEnumerator.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ask yourself "imagine if this were true".

If all the enumeration methods were on a single interface, how could two callers enumerate the same list at the same time?

There are two interfaces because one says, "You can enumerate me," while the other says, "here's an object that keeps track of a given enumeration task."

The `IEnumerable` interface is a factory that creates as many `IEnumerator` objects as you want. How and when those enumerators get used is up to the consumer.

Comment: +1. This is a good example of why the interfaces are separate and discrete. Another reason is that the same type collection could be enumerated different ways. Imagine a binary tree - you can perform prefix, infix, postfix, and breadth-first traversals (just to name a few). Keeping the interfaces separate allows different kinds of traversals to be performed on the same structure through a single, simple interface.

Answer (score 7):

`IEnumerable` implies that the object is a collection or source of data which can be iterated over in a linear fashion. `IEnumerator` is the interface for the actual implementation which performs the iteration.

Answer (score 4):

Because "IEnumerable" says "come, enumerate me" (and then you say- how, give me the Enumerator), however "IEnumerator"  says "I can enumerate your collection!" and you already have it, you don't need to get any more.

Answer (score 2):

You got very good answers here.   Just some emphasis.  An enumerator keeps state, it keeps track of the current object in the collection being enumerated.  Available through IEnumerator.Current.  And it knows how to change that state, IEnumerator.MoveNext().  Keeping state requires a separate object that stores the state.  That state can't be stored inside the collection object easily because there's only one collection object but there can be more than one enumerator.

I used the phrase "easily" because it is actually possible for a collection to keep track of its enumerators.  After all, it was a call to the collection class' GetEnumerator() method that returned the iterator.  There's one collection class in the .NET framework that does this, Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection.  It needed to implement a VB6 contract for its Collection class and that contract specifies that changing a collection while it is being enumerated is legal.  Which means that when the Collection is modified, it needs to some reasonable with all of the iterator objects that were created.

They came up with a pretty good trick, WeakReference might have been inspired by this.  Have a look-see at the code shown by Reflector.  Inspiring stuff.  Dig some more and find "version" in the collection classes.  Awesome trick.

Comment: I wonder why there hasn't been a cleaner collection available (at least prior to net 4.0) which could do that?  Enumerating through a collection and selectively deleting elements would seem like a common operation.

Comment: @super: because it is fundamentally breaking.  You might be able to compensate iterators for a single mutation of the collection.  But something like removing an element and inserting it back in another position is going to break something.  The iterator will see an element twice or not at all.  Beyond that, keeping track of all live instances of iterators is quite expensive.

Comment: I can understand that the 'normal' collections wouldn't support such features, but the Collection manages to have useful semantics which would be even more useful if they were implemented in a class without its quirkiness.  One wouldn't want such semantics everywhere, but at times they're nice.  Actually, I would have liked to have seen more flavors of iEnumerator; applications could select one based upon required semantics (some would add methods; others would just add guarantees).  A useful one would be iPurgeEnumerator: call a predicate with each item and delete if true.

Comment: Well, write your own.  You've got an example to build from.

Answer (score 0):

Because often the thing doing the enumerating is only tangentially (if at all) related to the thing being enumerated. If IEnumerable and IEnumerator were the same interface, they couldn't be shared, or you'd need to have some untyped argument on GetEnumerator that allowed you to pass in the object to be enumerated. Splitting them allows the enumeration infrastructure to be potentially shared across different types.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Bart De Smet's post on [minlinq](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2010/01/01/the-essence-of-linq-minlinq.aspx) I'm no longer convienced that splitting the two interfaces is strictly required.

For instance - In the above link, IEnumerable/IEnumerator is collaped to a single method Interface

```
Func<Func<Option<T>>>
```

and some basic implementations

```
public static class FEnumerable
{
    public static Func<Func<Option<T>>> Empty<T>()
    {
        return () => () => new Option<T>.None();
    }

    public static Func<Func<Option<T>>> Return<T>(T value)
    {
        return () =>
        {
            int i = 0;
            return () =>
                i++ == 0
                ? (Option<T>)new Option<T>.Some(value)
                : (Option<T>)new Option<T>.None();
        };
    }

    ...

}

public static Func<Func<Option<T>>> Where<T>(this Func<Func<Option<T>>> source, Func<T, bool> filter)
{
    return source.Bind(t => filter(t) ? FEnumerable.Return(t) : FEnumerable.Empty<T>());
}
```